# iOS copy properties creation of new objects, retain, memory allocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, copy

If I have a copy property and set it to another object, I actually create a new object with a retain count of 1.

```
@property (copy) myObject;
myobject = someOtherObject;
//&myOBject != &someOtherObject
```

At this point, let's call address of myObject &myObject1.

If I go and do this after I set myObject to someOtherObject

```
myObject = someOtherObject2
```

what happens to &myObject1? Now myObject point to a value that is equivalent to someOtherObject2's value but at a new memory address. What happens to the &myObject1 and is there anything still pointing to it?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `@property` statement in the question does not have a type supplied.

If `someOtherObject` is immutable a copy is not made, only the reference count in incremented and both `myobject` and `someOtherObject` point to the same object. That os all that is needed since an immutable object can not be changed.  A change to either pointer will change the single object.

If `someOtherObject` is mutable a copy is made and there are now two distinct instances. No change is made to the original `someOtherObject`. Both `my object` and `someOtherObject` point to separate instances and have no relation to each other. If they are mutable a change to one will not change the other.

Comment: so what happens if I set it to `someOtherObject` which is mutable, and then I set it to `someOtherObject2` which is also mutable? What happens to the `&myObject` after I set it a second time?

Comment: You need to specify what "it" is. It would be better to update your question with a full example specifying the types (mutable or immutable) of the object(s). A simple choice of types would be `NSMutableString` and `NSString`.